# Minification issue on route config angular js & typescript min safe

Tags: angularjs, typescript, bundling-and-minification, angularjs-ng-route

I have a bundle with several js files (generated by typescript files)

When I use minification on the bundle, the page fails.

The error on chrome console:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   AppModule due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: n

I isolated the problem to one of two files, the app.module and the app.routes as follows:

app.module:

```
((): void=> {
    var app = angular.module("AppModule", ['ngRoute', 'ngMessages', 'app.xxx.xxx.xxxModule', 'ngSanitize']);
    app.config(AppModule.Routes.configureRoutes);
})();
```

app.routes:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../../scripts/typings/angularjs/angular-route.d.ts" />
module AppModule {
    declare var staticsDir: string;

    export class Routes {
        static $inject = ["$routeProvider"];
        static configureRoutes($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when("/xxx", { controller: "Uni.controllers.xxx", templateUrl: staticsDir + "/projects/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.html", controllerAs: "xxx" });
            $routeProvider.when("/xxx2", { controller: "Uni.controllers.xxx2", templateUrl: staticsDir + "/projects/xxx2/xxx2/xxx2/xxx2.html", controllerAs: "xxx2" });
        }
    }
}
```

(ignore the xxx and module names, I sanitized them)

I am guessing the error I am seeing is regarding the $routeProvider. Is there problem in the inject? How should I inject this min safe?

Comment: You are setting $inject on Routes but not configureRoutes. Try `app.config(['$routeProvider', AppModule.Routes.configureRoutes])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for $routeProvider to be injected in your static function which is not min-safe. static $inject applies to Routes class constructor only. So you can either do:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', AppModule.Routes.configureRoutes])
```

Or if you want to make full use of Angular's DI:

```
    export class Routes {
        static $inject = ["$routeProvider"];

        constructor(private $routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider){
        }
        configureRoutes() {
            this.$routeProvider.when("/xxx", { controller: "Uni.controllers.xxx", templateUrl: staticsDir + "/projects/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.html", controllerAs: "xxx" });
            this.$routeProvider.when("/xxx2", { controller: "Uni.controllers.xxx2", templateUrl: staticsDir + "/projects/xxx2/xxx2/xxx2/xxx2.html", controllerAs: "xxx2" });
        }
    ...
    ...
    }
```

register it as a provider itself:

ie. `app.provider('myRoutes', Routes);`

and inject it into the config block:

```
app.config(['myRoutes', function(myRoutes){
    myRoutes.configureRoutes();
}]
```

(or sth similar)

Comment: Thanks, the first option works. I tried the second option, but since the constructor expect 1 argument it doesn't work, what should i pass him?

Comment: Ah of course. Was duck typing as usual and didn't think this through. Using the second solution would require the Routes class to be registered to angular's DI as a provider it self and you would have to inject that in the config (as services cannot be injected in config blocks).